# Can a Support class soldier have a total of 8 medikit uses?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

Can a support use 8 medikit heals when s/he has the **Tactical Rigging** foundry project (carry two items), the **Deep Pockets** skill (one extra use for consumable items) and the **Field Medic** skill (allows medikits to be used three times per battle)?

Or is the **Field Medic** skill ignored on the second item slot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer: No**

There is a 1-medikit limit per soldier (thanks ken).  Medikits, chitin plating, mind shields, nano-fiber vests, scopes, reaper rounds, and respirator implants are all limited to one-per-soldier.

[image]

Those restrictions were present in EU, too, when Deep Pockets meant only the Supports could have two items - and back then, it was a single 3-heal medikit and any other item.

However, I can confirm that Training Roulette can be fun - Deep Pockets stacks with Grenadier (each pile of grenades is 3 deep).  And you can equip two grenades, for a total of 6, each doing extra damage.

**Final answer:** Deep Pockets stacks with Field Medic (4 uses per medikit), but that's it.  No synergy with Tactical Rigging.