# Is the will cap in XCOM 150?

Tags: xcom-enemy-within

As the title says, is the will cap on XCOM 150?
I have some 100+ will soldiers and the `psi armor` and `mind shield` combo gives a total of 50 will.

In any instance the will of my soldiers never goes above 150.

Does that mean getting multiple mind shield is useless as I only need to give it to my psi leader with `psi armor` and `mind shield`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **No.**

I can find no evidence of a will cap.  Here are two screenshots indicating that Durand's will is well above 150.  This is on a Classic difficulty, EW save I found laying around.
[image: In-combat Will above 150]
[image: In-base Will boosted above 150 by items]
Furthermore, I conducted in-combat testing.  Megaera (152 will, counting medals, as reported in-mission) had a 82% chance to Mindfray and 52% chance to Mind Control an Ethereal.  Durand (181 will, same method) had a 100% chance to Mindfray the same Ethereal, and an 81% chance to Mind Control.  Using Psi Inspire to improve Durand's Will to 211 raised the odds of Mind Control to 100%.  If Durand (squad leader) walks near Megaera, Lead By Example changes his in-game will and success percentages to be equal to Durand's, even if she was Psi Inspired and he not.

As to the second question regarding Mind Shields, it is of course advantageous for each soldier to carry an individual mind shield - both for defense and offense.  However, note that you cannot equip more than one Mind Shield on the same soldier.  See my answer here for a list of limited items.  https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/172431/61910

It's possible there was a Will cap in EU (as opposed to EW).  Despite 30 playthroughs, I don't seem to have a save handy with multiple 100+ Will (psionic) soldiers.  In EW, it happens basically every playthrough.

Comment: hmmm. strange, what is the version of your game? think im going back to xcom now to see things.

Comment: This is EW on PC, Steam BuildID 209747.  If you know where/if XCOM displays a version number, let me know and I'll look for it.  As stated in the answer, I don't know about EU (but this question was tagged ONLY for EW).